# Graphviz: edge to record label in Python (gv)

Tags: python, graphviz

I'm having a hard time generating the following edge:

```
...
h1 -> "h2":f2;
```

as shown in this example: [datastruct](http://www.graphviz.org/content/datastruct)

Consider the following Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import gv

gh = gv.digraph('g')

gv.setv(gh, 'rankdir', "LR")

node = gv.protonode(gh)
gv.setv(node, 'shape', 'record')

n1 = gv.node(gh, "h1")

n2 = gv.node(gh, "h2")
gv.setv(n2, "label", "<f1> s1 | <f2> s2")

e = gv.edge(n1, n2)

gv.write(gh, "out.dot")
```

Which after execution gives the following output:

```
digraph g {
    node [label="\N"];
    graph [rankdir=LR];
    h1 [shape=record];
    h2 [label="<f1> s1 | <f2> s2", shape=record];
    h1 -> h2;
}
```

Which leaves me with the question how to obtain the edge shown above so it points to the correct record entry.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the headport to do that:

I've only done this in C but from what you show in python I assume that is something like this:

```
e = gv.edge(n1, n2)
gv.setv(e, "headport", "f1") # or another key from the records
```

This will create an edge like this:

```
h1 -> h2:f1;
```

You can also set the tailport if you need to point in the reverse direction.